Probability problem with independent (?) events
I was wondering if the following question is well posed. "In one school, 40% of the students are female. Furthermore, 20% of students study German. What is the probability that, given a student at random, it is a girl who does not study German?"
I doubt whether it is really correct to assume that the two events are independent, thus reaching the simple answer 8/25
